# Invertible matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Given three $n \times n$ matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$. Prove that if $AB+AC$ is an invertible matrix then $A$ is also an invertible matrix.

How can this be possible? I found that $B=A^{-1}-C$ and when I plug it in it says $I=I$. What would that mean?

Comment: The question is the problem. not the title

Answer (score 1):

We can prove the contrapositive by using determinants:

> If $A$ is not invertible, then $AB + AC$ is not invertible.

Suppose that $A$ is not invertible. Then $\det A = 0$. But then since:
$$
\det(AB + AC) = \det(A(B + C)) = (\det A)\cdot(\det(B+C)) = 0 \cdot \det(B + C) = 0
$$
it follows that $AB + AC$ is not invertible, as desired.

Comment: We can also prove it directly by using determinants.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, matrix addition commutes:
$$AB+AC=A(B+C)$$
Here is one of the inversion identities:
$$(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$$
Therefore, we have, if the premise is true:
$$[A(B+C)]^{-1}=(B+C)^{-1}A^{-1}$$
Thus, for the premise to be true, $A^{-1}$ has to exist. It has to exist because it has been factored out as an explicit term.

If it doesn't exist, then the final equality is incorrect, which would then cascade back upwards to the premise. Proof by contradiction:

Assume: $A^{-1}$ does not exist. Therefore, for some invertible matrix $U$, the following (a matrix inversion identity) does not hold:
$$U^{-1}A^{-1}=(AU)^{-1}$$
Let: $U$ be the sum of two other matrices: $B$, $C$. Then, the last component is equivalent to the following:
$$U=B+C$$
Thus, the following does not hold (substitution):
$$(AU)^{-1}=(A(B+C))^{-1}$$
Basically, we have "proven" that the given (or assumed) premise is false. Our logical argument lead to a contradiction of the premise, therefore, the assumption at the beginning about $A$ must be wrong.

Comment: Good question, @user46944, I am assuming that he wants what he gave in the body of the problem. It's not a full solution, but I think it addresses the issue. If you see a problem, let me know.

Comment: Looks like you were right.  The problem was in the body.

Comment: how do you prove that it's invertible? I don't quite understand..

Comment: I don't think I proved it was invertible, but I showed that if the premise is true, then it follows that the inversion of the matrix $A$ has to exist. Or else the premise would be false. I could recast it as a proof by contradiction, but that's basically working from the final answer back towards the beginning.

Comment: Can you explain why the premise is true? I'm having trouble understanding the last part. What does it prove exactly?

Comment: You said, "if $AB+AC$ is an invertible matrix,..." That means to me that you can assume it is true, and derive the rest of the statement from it.